# Looking for wpf, .net control like the one used in Catalyst Control Center

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-forms-designer

Maybe someone knows where can i find this control or similar one. It looks and works really great
[image: Radeon Catalyst screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control you're looking for is called *accordion*. It's a part of the WPF Toolkit, and a guide how to use one can be found on [this](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/02/20/How-to-play-the-Accordion-WPF-Toolkit.aspx) blog entry.